# Match string conditional on character before and after

Tags: python, regex

Regex is always giving me a headache. I am trying to match a pattern, where it would only match if and only if both characters before and after are not a digit. It is okay, if one of the characters is a digit.

I.e. for the string "Zeitraum vom 1. 6. -30. 6." i am trying to match the dash (-), however the pattern should not be matched for "12-3-2019" (where both characters before and after the dash are digits).

Currently I am trying exclusions, but that seems to match if neither of the characters are a digit.

```
[^\d]-[^\d]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an alternation:

```
(?<!\d)-|-(?!\d)
```

This matching an hyphen not preceeded by digit OR not followed by digit

Comment: Wonderful!! This seems to be working, could you explain what it does why? :D

Comment: @FabianBosler: `(?<!..)` construction is negative lookbehind, a zero-length assertion yhat make sure we haven't a digit before the current position.See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
r'-(?<!\d-(?=\d))'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fssgng/1)

It matches a `-` that is not preceded with a digit and `-` that is immediately followed with a digit.

Note that the `(?=\d)` lookahead  is required rather than a simple `\d` because `(?<!\d-\d)` after `-` would be able to fail the match when backtracking.

**Details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?<!` - start of a negative lookbehind: fail the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is

  - `\d` - a digit
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(?=\d)` - followed with `\d`
- `)`  - end of the lookbehind

Comment: Perfect, you guys are awesome. @Wiktor, will accept Totos answer, because he was fast and I find his solution marginally easier to read.

Comment: @FabianBosler My answer was the first, but you may suit yourself.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still trying to understand yours. Why does `3--3` matches? There is a digit, a hyphen and it's followed by a digit

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sometime, readability has priority over performance

Comment: @Cid In `3--3`, there is no hyphen that is enclosed with digits on both sides.

Comment: @Cid *readability has priority over performance* - sorry, I belong to another "regex school".  I always prefer performance when it comes to regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew still trying to figure out why you are repeating the hyphen in the negative lookbehind

Comment: @Cid You need to read about [back-to-the-future lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#position). That `-` must *consume* the hyphen so that the lookbehind pattern could stop consuming further and backtrack where we do not want it to. You may think of it as an "anchor".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it now makes sense I guess, I was missing that *current position in the string*. That site will be a good reading, I'm saving it